# Making image responsive which different parts has different links?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make an image responsive which different parts are mapped to different links. For the purpose I used [image-maps](http://image-maps.com/) and edited my image. But the image is not responsive. How can I do this. Please help me?

The html code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Tangelo Town</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>
  <body>

    <!--  <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12 lfont">
            <p>Tangelo Town</p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div> -->

         <img id="mainlogo" class="img-responsive center-block" src="image/mainlogo.png" border="0" width="3256" height="875" orgWidth="3256" orgHeight="875" usemap="#mainlogo" alt="" />

    <map name="mainlogo" id="ImageMapsCom-mainlogo">

      <area  alt="" title="main" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="802.75,359,870.75,581,1898.75,589,1948.75,751,2517,750,2493,587,2320,537,2327,350" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area shape="rect" coords="3254,873,3256,875" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="Image Map" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_0" />

      <area  alt="" title="home" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="275,3,302,84,501,174,810,205,378,80" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home2" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="9,63,11,100,105,175,301,217,493,228,516,209,488,182,97,118" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home3" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="62,211,72,245,162,297,409,311,509,296,531,259" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home4" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="109,352,183,407,311,418,531,360,546,325,154,330" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home5" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="158,462,157,497,198,529,404,489,556,426,557,370" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />


      <area  alt="" title="home6" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="241,579,291,623,393,603,557,512,579,443,382,513" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home7" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="313,681,315,679,376,712,510,633,604,542,611,503,428,592" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home8" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="411,725,409,760,445,785,513,756,594,674,638,615,642,566,623,563" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home9" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="496,799,500,828,531,835,623,757,663,697,678,639,668,620" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home10" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="588,855,615,871,655,841,717,707,716,668,683,680,593,823" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home1" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="2450,206,2600,196,2754,177,2946,85,2978,45,2983,11,2905,77,2567,163" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home2" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="2744,212,2766,228,2948,220,3147,178,3241,114,3250,72,3233,67,3140,126,2843,168,2770,186" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home3" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="2724,258,2730,282,2761,296,2868,309,2983,310,3074,301,3145,275,3199,228,3194,209,2791,245" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home4" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="2715,319,2840,332,2951,328,3101,328,3152,351,3074,405,2949,419,2825,398,2731,356,2714,338" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home5" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="2695,377,2712,372,2865,422,3009,457,3091,460,3099,501,3057,532,2931,517,2724,433,2702,408" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home5" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="2701,379,2714,426,2815,474,2894,502,3039,530,3099,500,3094,457" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home6" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="2683,447,2677,461,2688,492,2698,502,2748,531,2853,594,2907,616,2960,630,2997,616,3017,606,3017,577,2842,502" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home7" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="2649,507,2653,539,2719,606,2798,658,2859,703,2920,710,2943,688,2920,653,2760,559,2673,501" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home8" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="2620,562,2626,613,2665,672,2722,728,2762,766,2829,782,2853,760,2850,731,2703,614" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home9" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="2585,619,2600,618,2649,668,2769,792,2740,836,2694,814,2631,751,2598,686" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

      <area  alt="" title="home10" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="2544,670,2544,700,2573,796,2633,871,2661,866,2676,842,2580,693,2565,669" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
    </map>


    <!-- Image Map goes here -->


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        var x = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            x-=1;
            $('body').css('background-position', '0 ' + x + 'px');
            // $('body').css('background-position', '0 ' + x + 'px');
            // x+=1;
            // $('body').css('background-position', '0 ' + x + 'px');
        }, 5);
    })
    </script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using bootstrap templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> jQuery RWD Image Maps
>
> Allows image maps to be used in a responsive design by recalculating
>   the area coordinates to match the actual image size on load and
>   window.resize

https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps

I have not personally tested it. But it sounds quite promising.